# ¿Cuál es la palabra más común para un juguete deslizante que los niños usan en la nieve?

Tags: sustantivos, tiempo, juegos

La palabra en ingles es "sled". ¿Cuál sería su equivalente en español?

[image: picture of a sled]

[image: flyer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un trineo:

> 1. m. Vehículo provisto de cuchillas o de esquíes en lugar de ruedas para deslizarse sobre el hielo y la nieve.

([fuente](https://dle.rae.es/trineo))

El artículo de Wikipedia sobre trineos tiene un foto de un trineo de mi pais:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Trineo" es en verdad la palabra genérica.

En Argentina, utilizamos la palabra "culipatín" (en inglés, "bum sledge"), que tiene ribetes humorísticos, para referirnos al deslizador de plástico que suele ser utilizado por los niños, o por adultos con alma de niño.

[Culipatín](https://untref.edu.ar/diccionario/buscar.php?q=571&p=culipat%C3%ADn): Nombre popular de algún elemento para deslizarse sentado sobre la nieve, ya hoy industrializado.

[image]

Comment: bum sledge is not a sled in English. I never heard that anywhere.

Comment: "sledge" is BrE for AmE "sled". https://www.h-2-snow.com/sliding-pan-sledge

Comment: @Lambie "bum sledge" is the phrase used in Argentina, not great Britain or North America. The reason that you have never heard the phrase "bum sledge" in English, is because that phrase is not used in English, it is used in Argentinan Spanish.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Sounds British to me. Because it ain't Spanish. bum is the British word for ass or derrière. And bum sledge in British English is only a kind of paddle where you read end sits. It is not a proper sled. It is shaped like a round shovel.